# WriteLine char[ ] + something

Tags: c#, char

why this strange thing happens that when I try to write `char[] word` to a console via

```
Console.WriteLine(word);
```

I got a correct result, but when I write

```
Console.WriteLine(word + " something");
```

I get " `System.Char[]` something "?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because your first attempt is writing out a `char` array, which `Console.WriteLine` accepts as valid input using an overload.

```
Console.WriteLine(word);
```

But your second result appears wrong because you are combining a `char[]` with a string literal. So `Console.WriteLine` tries to make your `char[]` also a string, by doing this:

```
Console.WriteLine(word.ToString() + " something");
```

Notice it calls `.ToString()` on the `word` (internally) to make it a `string`. The `ToString` method on the `char[]` returns it's **type** not it's value. Thus giving you the odd result.

You can fix it by doing:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(word) + " something");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because for

```
Console.WriteLine(word);
```

its calling the [`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxcchfk6.aspx) overload which takes a `char[]`.

In

```
Console.WriteLine(word + " something");
```

its calling `ToString()` on `word` which results in `System.Char[]`

To output it correctly, try:

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(word) + " something");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it happens is **string** overloads operator+ to behave like that.
If you want to use make it that way you have to first create a string out of your char[] word.
try

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(word) + " something");
```

Comment: are you sure 'string(word)' works? cause to me it says "Invalid expression term 'string'"

Comment: new string(word) should

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine()` has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxcchfk6.aspx) which takes `char[]` as a parameter.

`"something"` is a [*string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), when you try to concatenate `string` and `char[]`, `.ToString()` method is calling auto.

Try this instead;

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(word) + " something");
```